# mysql query with between date with time interval

Tags: mysql, date, between

I have a table with **created_time** field.
There is a requirement to find out all entries between two dates, between  a particular time interval.
For example, if I want to find all entries between April 1st 2018 to April 30th 2018 with time interwal between 2.30 PM to 4.30 PM, what would be the ideal query ?

```
select * from my_table where created_time between '2018-04-01
14:30:00' and '2018-04-30 16:30:00'
```

Comment: This query will give all entries between these dates. I want entries between 14.30 and 16.30 only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split compare `Date` value and `Time` value.

You can try this query.

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    created_time  DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-04-01 14:00:00');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-04-01 14:50:00');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-04-04 10:00:00');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-04-01 15:00:00');
```

**Query**

```
select * from my_table 
where 
    (created_time between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-30') 
AND 
    (CAST(created_time AS time) > CAST('14:30:00' AS time) AND CAST(created_time AS time) < CAST('16:30:00' AS time))
```

**[Results]**:

```
|         created_time |
|----------------------|
| 2018-04-01T14:50:00Z |
| 2018-04-01T15:00:00Z |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/400783/1)